# Google Tag Manager. Tracking link click through a funnel

Tags: google-tag-manager

I had a question about Google Tag Manager. (I also felt bad for having the IT guy fix my mistakes on my simple click tag)

I wanted to track when a user enters a specific url when they click a link button on the homepage.
This is what it looks like
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpJ3f.png)

This is my idea on what the Tag and Trigger should look like
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URRtM.png)

But I'm worried about having the trigger be fired when there is another page in the funnel

Also if the only way to do this is in the goal feature of GA that is good to know also. (I currently don't have the permissions here)

Thanks for responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is difficult to achieve exactly what you're describing (it would involve storing data in cookies and then using these cookies to conditionally fire tags), there is a better way to achieve what I assume is your ultimate objective: an analysis of the shopping funnel.

Specifically, the Google Analytics [enhanced ecommerce](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014841?hl=en) module has a dedicated report (the Conversions > Ecommerce > Shopping Behavior report) that shows you exactly this. It shows you the number of sessions for each stage of your shopping experience (product view -> add to cart -> checkout -> purchase) along with drop-off rates and volumes between each of these steps.

It is a little bit more involved to implement enhanced ecommerce but the final result is definitely worth it for an ecommerce business. Instructions for implementation of enhanced ecommerce (using Google Tag Manager) can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce).

Answer (score 0):

GTM is hit based without any notion of persistence. So by default this will not work.

You would need a custom HTML tag with a javascript function that sets a cookie, or writes a value to localstorage, when the button is clicked.

Then on your destination page you can check if the cookie exists and fire the tag accordingly.

I don't think the goal feature in GA can do that, either. A goal is registered when you hit a destination URL or event, you cannot specify conditions other than the destination.

Comment: Technically, you can specify a funnel when defining a goal in GA and the report will show you how many sessions passed through the different stages of the funnel before arriving at the final destination. This can be found under the Conversions > Goals > Funnel Visualization report.

Comment: @faridghar The button click is an event, the destination is a pageview. You cannot configure a destination goal to fire only when an event has happened, and you cannot mix events and pageviews in a single goal.

Comment: True in which case you have two options 1) Use GA360 which does support mixing events and page views in the same custom funnel or 2) Treating the link click as a page view which is basically a hack that will inflate your page views. The proper way to do this would be to use enhanced eCommerce and treat the link as a product list. This way you can easily assess the efficacy of this link (i.e. product list) at driving transactions using the Conversions > Ecommerce > Product List Performance report. I've suggested enhanced ecommerce in my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. It sounds like enhanced eCommerce is the correct solution